# Unable to setup hadoop multinode cluster without admin privileges

Tags: linux, hadoop, hdfs, admin-rights

I am trying to set up hadoop multi node cluster in linux, but i don't have admin privileges. I was referring to some video tutorials on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DteSiloXesw and many other.
 I always get struck on the step where i need to edit /etc/hosts file because i don't have admin rights. Is there any other hack or workaround so that i can set up multi node hadoop cluster without admin privileges.

Thanks

Comment: Chaning /etc/hosts is required only if you are not able to resolve machines using name I think otherwise it is not needed.AlsoDo you have sudo rights?

Comment: @SachinJanani hi, I don't have sudo rights even

Comment: Oh ok then are your machine names are resolved properly,if not then you need to contact admin

Answer (score 0):

/etc/hosts file is used for translating hostnames that you use to their IP.

You can skip this step altogether if your DNS is properly resolving the hostnames.

Having said that, you can ask you admin team to provide you selective sudo access if they can't provide you the root access. One of those sudo access could be editing /etc/hosts file.